# Getting null value submitting my form to a new window using java script

Tags: javascript

```
function openWindowWithGraph(selectedItems){
            var i=0;
            var form = document.createElement("form");
            form.setAttribute("method", "post");
            form.setAttribute("action", "http://localhost:8080/cmonitor/app/solarPlant/showChart");
            form.setAttribute("target", "formresult");

            alert(selectedItems[0].solarPanel.id);
            for(i=0;i<selectedItems.length;i++){
                var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");              
                hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "solarPanelIds["+i+"]");
                hiddenField.setAttribute("value", selectedItems[i].solarPanel.id);
                form.appendChild(hiddenField);
            }

            document.body.appendChild(form);
            window.open('','formresult','width=1000,height=1000,toolbar=no ');
            alert("hello");
            form.submit();
        }
```

here is my spring controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/showChart",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView showChart(@RequestParam(required=false) Long[] selectedItemIds){
        System.out.println(selectedItemIds);  //getting null in controller
        return new ModelAndView("noHeader/solarPlant/chart");
    }
```

any kind of help will be greatly appreciated 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Server-side JavaScript? Are you saying that the JS in your question runs on the server and not in the browser? It sure doesn't look that way.

Comment: no my js runs in the browser but on server i am getting null value

Comment: I don't know Spring, but it looks like you are using a PHP naming convention for your form fields and assuming that Spring will handle them in the same way. I don't know Spring, but I've never seen anything use PHP's square bracket in field name to array syntax except PHP.

Comment: it is java script (client side code) will be same for all server side technology

Comment: Spring is **not** client side code or JavaScript.

Comment: yeah i am talking about my js not my spring controller

Comment: You have the "getting null" comment in the Spring code…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my testing, you cannot use '[' or such in a form name. Although it sends it (URL-escaped) in the POST request, at least PHP wouldn't accept the escaped or unescaped form.

Changing this line:

```
hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "solarPanelIds["+i+"]");
```

to

```
hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "solarPanelIds"+i);
```

works (as long as you update the server side variable).

You might also wish to consider using the technique of submitting a form asynchronously via a hidden iframe, if you are not tied to having a popup.

Comment: PHP depends on fields being named with square brackets to decide if it should represent them as an array. `solarPanelIds[1]` should work fine, but you need to access it as `$_POST['solarPanelIds'][1]` and not `$_POST['solarPanelIds[1]']`

Comment: Ah yes, true, thanks--I knew that was true for radio buttons (where you particularly want them that way), so should have realized that.